# How can i gain access control for autorun.ini file in FAT32 USB storage

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8.1, autorun, cacls

I want to remove autorun.ini file from my USB storage but unable to remove and I've tried many times by following procedure:

```
I:\> attrib autorun.ini -r -a -s -h
```

and I always get "access denied" message.

I've also tried using windows "cacls" command, but this is not working for FAT32 file system.

In windows 8.1, security tab is not available for autorun.ini file in USB storage, so that this is impossible to gain access control.

Comment: Is this a usb stick or external hard drive? Are other files on the device writeable?

Comment: Yes this is USB stick(pen drive), and other files are writeable.

Comment: Doe this USB stick have a physical lock on it to protect the content?

Comment: No it has no physical lock key.

Comment: It may be possible the file is locked by some malware process. You can use this utility http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker to see which process is locking the file. Unlock the file and then remove it.

Answer (score 1):

FAT32 does not have any permissions so that is why the security tab is not shown.

The most likely answer for access denied is that the file is in use.  Try disabling autorun on your PC and then deleting the file.

Alternatively it could be being protected by malware. It is worth running an antivirus scan to rule that out if you don't already regularly run one.

Least likely but also possible is that the file is being protected at a hardware level, this can happen due to corruption or where a manufacturer has some default files that they don't want you to change.